# Этимология слов трындеть и трындец

Tags: этимология

Трындеть - разговаривать.Трындец - конец,капут.Какова этимология этих слов?

Comment: Мне вот это нравится: "твердить, говорить все свое, одно и то же" родственно рус. трынде́ть "болтать попусту, пустомелить", трынды́чать "тараторить", трындычи́ха. отсюда - https://vk.com/wall-16843964_4580#:~:text=Тры́ндить%20твр.%20%22твердить%22%20(Даль)%20происходит,память%22%2C%20долбежить%20%22колотить%2C%20бить%22%20(Даль)

Comment: ...конец,капут.Какова... Клавишу пробела смазывали давно?

Comment: У Даля есть слово 
ТРЫНДИТЬ
твер. твердить, говорить все свое, одно и то же. Трынды, астрах. тралды, дразнят жидконгого.

То есть само слово не новое.

Капут - это немецкое слово. Капец - скорее всего производный эвфемизм от капут и матерного слова. И трындец по такому же принципу.

Comment: А может, трындец, это - "ну я же говорил".